# Sending Image to the MySQL database with Android

Tags: android, mysql, json

I have the current application which sends and retrieves data from a MySQL database but the information so far I was transferring was String. How can I update the code below to be able to send images too.

```
public class NewProductActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputDesc;
EditText inputImg;
Button btnTakePhoto;
ImageView imgTakenPhoto;
private static final int CAM_REQUREST = 1313;
// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://buiud.com/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_product);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
    inputDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);
    inputImg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    // Create button
    Button btnCreateProduct = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCreateProduct);

    // button click event
    btnCreateProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new product in background thread
            new CreateNewProduct().execute();
        }
    });
    btnTakePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == CAM_REQUREST) {
          Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
      }
}

class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUREST);
    }
}
/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new product
 * */
class CreateNewProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewProductActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Product..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String description = inputDesc.getText().toString();
        String image = inputImg.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created product
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create product
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

Note: I have added the image field as I did other String fields, but the application now stops, it can't convert the picture as Text obviously. Let me know what you think, or any sort of casting available. I just take a photo and that photo is to be sent to MySQL.

Comment: store the path of the image in the database

Comment: you can save the photo in device's external or internal memory and save the path in MySQL database

Comment: Code example would be much appreciated