# Send image to http server from Android

Tags: android, image, xampp, server

I know that this question is "over-answered" but I'm really desperate!!
At first sorry for my bad english.
GOAL:
I use XAMPP and I want to store in a server an image sent by an Android app.

I have read lots of tutorial but nothing works!! 
I found and tried this code of Keaton but it doesn't works! There aren't errors or crashes but the image  doesn't really sent to the server.

[Keaton code - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966910/androidhow-to-upload-mp3-file-to-http-server)

I've paste this function in a new project and run with only this function.
I've Android Jelly Bean 4.3 and I tried this app with the phone completely unplugged by pc!
Server is running.
I think that I have all permission on server... (I have done other works on it)

Help me pls!
Thank you

Comment: I'm trying 5-6 different codes taken on the web... not works.
I have a problem...

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21302340/android-application-to-send-image-to-mysql?rq=1 and this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21300842/sending-image-to-the-mysql-database-with-android?rq=1